# how to sort this data by in ascending order?

Tags: mysql, sql

Am trying to retrieve data from Database in Ascending order.

My query was

```
select pid 
from `patient_list` t1, patient_info t2 
where pid > '2000' and t2.id=t1.id 
order by pid asc 
limit 10
```

but the data is like

```
pid
2221
2223
2224
2227
**223**
2238
2239
2242
2245
2247
**225**
```

How to sort this ?

Comment: I think that was only for making these 2 columns bold in the first edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, clean the data. Secondly, cast to int. Thirdly sort and/or filter.

```
select pid from `patient_list` t1, patient_info t2 
where replace(pid, "*", "") + 0 > 2000 and t2.id = t1.id 
order by replace(pid, "*", "") + 0
limit 1
```

Note that you are also filtering on that field so you should use the replacement logic twice.

Answer (score 6):

Your data is sorted alphanumeric. To force a numerical sort you must cast the data into a number. For instance with `pid * 1`

```
select pid 
from `patient_list` t1, patient_info t2 
where pid > '2000' 
and t2.id=t1.id 
order by pid * 1 asc 
limit 1
```

Since your `pid` is of a string type you should consider changing that to an `int`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. but using with this am getting data like Full Texts  
  3
  4
  5
  6
  7
  21
  22
  23

Comment: @jaya: I don't understand what you mean. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

your pid-columns seems not to be a numeric fieldtype, so the values are treaten as string values.
in your case the order-by-algorithm is sorting the whole string char by char and not by the actual value of the number

`2227, 223, 2238` will sort like `AAAG, AAB, AABG`

i assume its varchar, try to change it to `INT`

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that, you should sort by both length of pid and itself. This trick will work even for non-integer pids.

```
select pid from patient_list t1, patient_info t2 
where length(pid) >= 4 and pid > '2000' and t2.id=t1.id 
order by length(pid) asc, pid asc limit 1
```